# Use VBA to Disable data previews to download in the background (Excel)

Tags: excel, vba, refresh

I have a VBA code that runs PowerQuery refresh on execution. This query is very slow if the user has the setting in the picture below on. (Data --> Get Data --> Query Options --> Current File Data Load --> Allow data previews to download in the background.)

What i need to do with VBA, is turn this off (=untick the box) before refreshing. Does anyone know how to do this?

Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You include that in your script.

i.e.

```
Selection.ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
```